# Как в node.js отправить GET на другой сервер?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Нужно отправить GET запрос с параметрами `param=edit` и `value=10` на другой сервер (`different_domain.com/edit.php`) и полученный ответ записать в переменную `answer`

Answer (score 2):

Например воспользоваться модулем `request`, [проект на github](https://github.com/request/request).
Модуль `request` - это мощная обёртка для работы с http-запросами.
`request` обладает множеством преимуществ, включаю эмуляцию работы формы, авторизацию, работу с редиректами, подготовку параметров  и т.д.

```
const request = require('request');
const url = '<ВАШ_URL>'; // http://www.mysite.ru/index.php
var answer = '';

request({
   method: 'GET',
   url: url,
   // параметры GET-запроса
   // index.php?param=edit&value=10
   qs: {
     param: 'edit',
     value: 100
   }
  }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // console.log(body);
    // валидация и 
    // обработка полученного ответа, заголовков
    answer = body;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'different_domain.com',
  path: '/edit.php?value=10&param=edit'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var answer;
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    answer = chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log("Запрос завершен");
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

P.S. Подобные ситуации подробно описаны в сети, почитайте: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/

Comment: А потом будет вопрос - почему answer пустой :)